# era Interim data extracting a variable from RNetCDF

Tags: r, extract, netcdf, temperature

My goal is extract temperature, date from each latitude and longitude from this ERA interim data file  (see link https://www.dropbox.com/s/lnxetoy1911q5sg/_grib2netcdf-atls17-95e2cf679cd58ee9b4db4dd119a05a8d-vMTGKo.nc?dl=0)

I am using  RNetCDF package in R but when I used the var.get.nc function my values are all negatives. I am stuck at this step.  I know there is data in the netcdf as I opened it ArcMap. My codes are below

```
require(RNetCDF)
nc_in1   = open.nc("_grib2netcdf-atls17-95e2cf679cd58ee9b4db4dd119a05a8d-vMTGKo.nc")
# get all Air temperature data data:
 temp      <- var.get.nc(nc_in1, "t2m")
head(temp)
```

-8355 -8399 -8444 -8487 -8531 -8576

#Data structure are as follows

```
    print.nc(nc_in1)
    dimensions:
    longitude = 561 ;
    latitude = 321 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (8 currently)
    variables:
    float longitude(longitude) ;
            longitude:units = "degrees_east" ;
            longitude:long_name = "longitude" ;
    float latitude(latitude) ;
            latitude:units = "degrees_north" ;
            latitude:long_name = "latitude" ;
    int time(time) ;
            time:units = "hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:0.0" ;
            time:long_name = "time" ;
            time:calendar = "gregorian" ;
    short t2m(longitude, latitude, time) ;
            t2m:scale_factor = 0.001140245 ;
            t2m:add_offset = 264.0577 ;
            t2m:_FillValue = -32767 ;
            t2m:missing_value = -32767 ;
            t2m:units = "K" ;
            t2m:long_name = "2 metre temperature" ;

           // global attributes:
            :Conventions = "CF-1.6" ;
            :history = "2016-04-30 18:18:33 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-1.14.5: grib_to_netcdf /data/data01/scratch/_mars-atls02-95e2cf679cd58ee9b4db4dd119a05a8d-E36dti.grib -o /data/data01/scratch/_grib2netcdf-atls17-95e2cf679cd58ee9b4db4dd119a05a8d-vMTGKo.nc -uti
```

I was able to use the same package and codes to achieve the same using MERRA data but I cant seem to find my error in this ERA interim dataset. Any assistance to solve this issue in RNetCDF would be helpful as I am little familiar with this package and still learning about .nc files.

Comment: Just a fast comment: for dealing with gridded data in R, I highly recommend the `raster` package.

Comment: Thank for your comment my skills in R is not sharp. But would raster package allow me to convert the data to a dataframe extract the  date and its corresponding lat and longitude in the same row?..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The raster package is defineitely the way to go for R gridded data, it's very versatile and easy to use. However, if you just need to perform very simple tasks, you may be better off with ncdf4 or RNetCDF as you already did.

Comment: I am interested build a time series of temperature for each latitude and longitude from .nc file. So I would have a columns of Date, Temperature, Latitude and Long ( as I have many .nc files). Hence that why I was using RNetCDF but i have issues as outlined above and not certain how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution your issue is that you need to unpack the data

```
 temp      <- var.get.nc(nc_in1, "t2m", unpack= TRUE)
```